# A formal definition of the number 4 according to Frege and Russell.

Tags: logic

I want to give  a formal definition of the number 4 according to Frege and Russell. Are the definitions similar?
Edit:
I would really like to see how the number 4 is defined according to these two belifes, formally, because I am having trouble doing so.

Comment: More or less... see [Frege's Analysis of Cardinal Numbers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#S3) and [Russell’s Work in Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell/#RWL).

Comment: Ok, so how would A formal definition of the number 4 look like according to each ? Thanks !

Comment: Would you add to your Question a few words about what interests you about the "formal definition"?  While Russell and Whitehead formalized the foundations of mathematics in set theory, Frege formalized such topics in what he called [Begriffsschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift) or *concept-writing*.

Comment: I did edit my question. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: For Frege, if you are not satisfied with the modern "translation" in SEP's entry, you can see Gregory Landini, [Frege’s Notations : What They Are and How They Mean](https://books.google.it/books?id=kDZQvy6-9rwC&pg=PA80) (2012), page 80.

Comment: For W&R, in a slightly modified version [Vol I (1910), page 364](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/aat3201.0001.001/400?page=root;rgn=full+text;size=100;view=pdf) : $^*52 \cdot 01$. $1=_{\text {Def}} \{ \alpha \mid (\exists x)(\alpha= \{ x \}) \}$.

Comment: And page 376 : $^*54 \cdot 01$. $2=_{\text{Def}} \{ \alpha \mid (\exists x)(x \in \alpha \land \alpha \setminus \{ x \} \in 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Frege—Russell definition states that the natural number $n$ is the property common to all collections of $n$ objects", according to [Subrecursion: Functions and Hierarchies](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Subrecursion.html?id=ob5PAQAAIAAJ)

Comment: As an informal proposition this is likely to help with a historical perspective, but it seems lacking as a "formal definition", something that both Frege and Russell were at pains to supply.

Comment: Ah, you're right. For some reason I assumed that the intentions of the OP did not require a definition much more formal than that, due to the aura of the question I perceived — as if it was more philosophical than mathematical.